# how to retrieve a line with spaces with comma as separator?

Tags: java, android

I have this record in my game.txt file

```
menard,menard mabunga,0 
francis,francis mabunga,0 
angelica,francis mabunga,1
```

I access the file and store it in an array list using this code;

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.game));
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (s.hasNext()){
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
```

And use this function to load a random line;

```
public static String randomLine(ArrayList list) {
        return (String) list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()));
    }
```

When I try to print the result of the randomLine function using `System.out.println(randomLine(list));` the output is `mabunga,0` only.

Now, how can I retrieve a line with spaces with comma as separator?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading words instead of lines. Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`. So, this should be your code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.game));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.nextLine()); // Change here!!
}
s.close();
```

I prefer `BufferedReader` over `Scanner` if the goal is to read lines.

Comment: thanks @martjin, follow-up question... how can I exclude the lines with value of 1?

Comment: Use this: `String line = s.nextLine(); if (!line.endsWith("1")) list.add(line);`

Answer (score 0):

You should instantiate Random ony once, and store a reference to it. Otherwise, `nextInt()` will always return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `String Tokenizer` (or a `Stream Tokenizer` if you want to separate them while reading the file). Set the separator to ",". Then you should be fine.

In the randomLine function use the following piece of code, instead of yours:

```
public static String randomLine(ArrayList list) {
        return (String) list.get((int)(Math.Random()*list.size()));
    }
```